# First instance after specific string

Tags: regex, url, vbscript

So, I have this RegEx that captures a specific string I need (thanks to Shawn Mehan):

```
>?url:\'\/watch\/(video[\w-\/]*)
```

It works great, but now I need to mod my criteria.  I need to capture ONLY the first URL after EACH instance of: `videos:[{title:`. Bolded all instances below and also bolded the first URL I'd want captured as an example.

How might I approach this?  I have a VBScript that will dump each URL to a text file, so I just need help selecting the correct URLs from the blob below. Thinking something like, "if this string is found, do this, loop".  Setting the regex global to false should only grab the first instance each round, right? A basic example would help.

I believe I have all of the pieces I need, but I'm not quite sure how to put them together. I'm expecting the code below to loop through and find the index of each instance of "videos:[{title:", then the regex to grab the first URL after (regexp global set to false) based on the pattern, then write the found URL to my text file, loop until all are found.  Not working...

(larger portion of html_dump: http://pastebin.com/6i5gmeTB)

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegExp = new RegExp
objRegExp.Global = False
objRegExp.Pattern  = ">?url:\'\/watch\/(video[\w-\/]*)"
filename = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)     & "\html_dump.txt" 'Text file contains html

set urldump = fso.opentextfile(filename,1,true)

do until urldump.AtEndOfStream
strLine = urldump.ReadLine()

strSearch = InStrRev(strLine, "videos:[{title:")  'Attempting to find the position of "videos:[{title:" to grab the first URL after.

If strSearch >0 then

Set myMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strLine)  'This matches the URL pattern.
For Each myMatch in myMatches
strCleanURL = myMatch.value
next

'===Writes clean urls to txt file...or, it would it if worked===

filename1 = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URLsClean.txt"  'Creates and writes to this file

set WriteURL = fso.opentextfile(filename1,2,true)
WriteURL.WriteLine strCleanURL
WriteURL.Close

else
End if


loop
urldump.close
```

var streams = [ {streamID:138, cards:[{cardId: 59643,cardTypeId: 48,clickCount: 84221,occurredOn: '2015-08-17T15:30:17.000-07:00',expiredOn: '',header: 'Latest News Headlines', subHeader: 'Here are some of the latest headlines from around the world.', link: '/watch/playlist/544/Latest-News-Headlines', earn: 3, playlistRevisionID: 3427, image: 'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380591%2F519029502_3_o.jpg', imageParamPrefix: '?', size: 13, durationMin: 15, durationTime: '14:34',pos:0,trkId:'2gs55j6u0nz8',  true,**videos:[{title:**'World\'s First Sky Pool Soon To Appear In South London',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380509%2F519025436_c_140_105.jpg',durationTime:'0:39',url:'/**watch/video/716424/worlds-first-sky-pool-soon-to-appear-in-south-london**',rating:'4.2857'},{title:'Treasure Hunters Find $4.5 Million in Spanish Coins',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380462%2F519023092_3.jpg',durationTime:'0:54',url:'/watch/video/715927/treasure-hunters-find-4-5-million-in-spanish-coins',rating:'4.25'},{title:'Former President Jimmy Carter Says Cancer Has Spread to Brain',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380499%2F519024920_c_140_105.jpg',durationTime:'1:59',url:'/watch/video/716363/former-president-jimmy-carter-says-cancer-has-spread-to-brain',rating:'2.8889'},{title:'Josh Duggar Had Multiple Accounts on AshleyMadison.Com',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380505%2F519025222_c_140_105.jpg',durationTime:'1:30',

Comment: Switch to PowerShell (v3 or newer) and use `ConvertFrom-Json`. Seriously.

Comment: Is this type of search difficult?  Something like if "videos:[{title:" found, start searching from there and grab first occurrence where matches regex, repeat down.  What I'm not sure how to do is tell it where in the txt file to start searching.

Comment: Still can't get it right.  Trying to find the index of "videos:[{title:" but it's still returning everything, not just the urls where immediately after videos:[{title:

Comment: Regular expressions can get messy rather quickly. It's a lot easier to check properties of an object (which is what `ConvertFrom-Json` produces) than parsing a string yourself.

Comment: Is the above actually your input string? Particularly, does the input really have values `true`/`false` *without a key* before the `videos` key? Or is it `something:true`/`something:false` like the rest of the data? The former would be invalid JSON (AFAIK), so it would have to be removed before further processing. Where does the input come from? Is it JavaScript code you extracted from somewhere?

Comment: Oh yea, that's weird.  Here's  paste bin of a larger portion: http://pastebin.com/6i5gmeTB.  The way my script works now, is it dumps this to a text file, then the code I'm trying to create now would read this blob from the text file and pull out only the wanted URLs and dump those line by line into another text file.  The wanted URLS = only the first URL AFTER each instance of "videos:[{title:"  Not to be mistaken with URLs following "{title:" (don't want those)

Comment: What we need is a *representative* sample, not an even larger one.

Comment: They are both representative of the data I need to parse.  If the second is too large, use the first.  You should just be able to copy what I've provided into a text file and test your code against it.  Or, maybe I'm not following what you're requiring.

Comment: I edited my OP to include the code I have so far...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input comes from a file and is in correct JSON format you could do something like this in PowerShell:

```psh
$jsonfile = 'C:\path\to\input.txt'

$json = Get-Content $jsonfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.streams.cards | ForEach-Object { $_.videos[0].url }
```

The above is assuming that `streams` is the topmost key in your JSON data.

Note that the code requires at least PowerShell v3.

Comment: Not sure how to run this...  I have powershell open.  Can I paste this into a text file and rename the extension to something?  Also, where will also output to a text file?  Also, don't know my powershell version, but it says 2009.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I'm thinking this won't work for me.  I need to be able to manipulate what I receive here to work for my specific need, but I don't know enough about powershell to do that.